# How to use resources in code, where filename is required? C++/CLI

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, embedded-resource, resx

I`m working on a project, linked with MS PowerPoint Interop and one of interop functions, which adds picture to a slide, requires filename of a picture.

How can I route a picture, stored in .resx, to that function?

Or is it possible to set some of resouces to be "Unpacked" to some folder while application is executed to be available for that function?

Comment: You'll have to use ResourceManager::GetObject().  Get guidance from a sample C# project to which you add resources, look at the auto-generated Resources.Designer.cs file.

Comment: @HansPassant auto-generated...thanks, I`ll look for it. Hope, it is what i need.